# PPPOE : How to Set fixed calling number

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, pppoe

I'm facing issue with PPPOE connection,

**Error logs :**

```
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home pppd[4141]: PPP session is 1769
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home pppd[4141]: Connected to 00:27:0e:14:d1:04 via interface eth0
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home pppd[4141]: Using interface ppp0
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home pppd[4141]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home NetworkManager[1131]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home NetworkManager[1131]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home NetworkManager[1131]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home pppd[4141]: CHAP authentication failed: bad username or password
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home pppd[4141]: CHAP authentication failed
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home pppd[4141]: Connection terminated.
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home NetworkManager[1131]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Dec 29 15:50:20 rahul-home avahi-daemon[859]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
Dec 29 15:50:22 rahul-home pppd[4141]: Terminating on signal 15
Dec 29 15:50:22 rahul-home pppd[4141]: Exit.
```

**Success Log**

```
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: PPP session is 22450
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: Connected to 00:07:e9:a5:a8:85 via interface eth0
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: Using interface ppp0
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home NetworkManager[1131]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home NetworkManager[1131]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home NetworkManager[1131]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: CHAP authentication succeeded: Welcome.
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: peer from calling number 00:07:E9:A5:A8:85 authorized
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: local  IP address xx.xx.xx.xx
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: remote IP address 172.31.29.1
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: primary   DNS address xx.xx.xx.xx
Dec 29 15:50:24 rahul-home pppd[4189]: secondary DNS address xx.xx.xx.xx
```

**My Observation**

I have tested with n number of attempt, but I've notice that dialer get connected when it using peer calling number `00:07:E9:A5:A8:85`, 
but I'm unable to fix this. with help of `man pppd`, I've tried following option in `/etc/ppp/options`

```
allow-number 00:07:E9:A5:A8:85  # Tested showing not authorized
remotenumber 00:07:E9:A5:A8:85  # Tested but not working
```

**Temporary Solution**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Retry pppoe until get connected

rndc stop

interval=2
n=0
pppstats && { echo "Internet is working"; exit 1; }
until nc -vzw1 titanic 80 
do
    poff -a ||
    pon dsl-provider
    sleep $interval 
    ((n++))
done

echo "Dialer Connected after total retry: $n"
plog
/etc/init.d/bind9 start
```

**Specs**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy

pppd version 2.4.5
```

**Question**

How do I set fix calling number in pppoe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling debug logs, I've found the solution

**The issue was**

There are two groups in our local ISP, we can see using :

```
root@rahul-home:~# pppoe-discovery 
AC-Ethernet-Address: 00:07:e9:a5:a8:85
Access-Concentrator: spidernet
       Service-Name: spidernet
--------------------------------------------------
AC-Ethernet-Address: 00:27:0e:14:d1:04
Access-Concentrator: Fivenet
       Service-Name: 5network
--------------------------------------------------
```

the calling number which I was asking it is actually ACNAME `00:07:e9:a5:a8:85` i.e spider.

**Now the question is How do I set fix ACNAME and Service name ?**

I've checked man pages but haven't found related to the same, but after Googling I've found the the [solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pppoeconf/+bug/251241), which is Bug reported in 2010, but still not updated man pages.

**and the solution**

we need to go to the /`etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider` configuration file. There is a line:
`plugin rp-pppoe.so ethX`

Where we can specify multiple options such as:

`plugin rp-pppoe.so rp_pppoe_service SERVICE_NAME rp_pppoe_ac ACCESS_CONCENTRATOR ethX`